# How to order columns of old/new values such that the ith old value = the (i-1)th new value

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

**Edit:** title suggestions welcome. This probably has a name, but I don't know what it is and could not find something similar.

---

**Edit2:** I've rewritten the problem to try and explain it more clearly. In both versions, I think I've met the site standards by putting forth an explanation, reproducible example, and my own solution... if you could suggest improvements before downvoting, that would be appreciated.

---

I have user entered data from a system containing these three columns:

- date: timestamps in `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` format; however `%S=00` for all cases
- old: the old value of this observation
- new: the new value of this observation

If the user entered data within the same minute, then sorting by the timestamp alone is insufficient. We end up with a "chunk" of entries that may or may not be in the correct order. To illustrate, I've replaced dates with integers and present a correct and jumbled case:

[image: correct-vs-jumbled]

How do we know the data is in the correct order? When each row's value for `old` equals the previous row's value for `new` (ignoring the first/last row where we have nothing to compare to). Put another way: `old_i = new_(i-1)`. This creates the matching diagonal colors on the left, which are jumbled on the right.

Other comments:

- there may be multiple solutions, as two rows may have the same values for `old` and `new` and thus are interchanbeable
- if an ambiguous chunk occurs by itself (imagine the data is *only* the rows where `date=1` above), any solution will suffice
- if the ambiguous chunk occurs with a unique date before and/or after, these serve as additional constraints and must be considered to achieve the solution
- consider the case with back to back ambiguous chunks as bonus; I plan to ignore these and am not sure they even exist in the data

My data set is  much larger, so my end solution will involve using `pandas.groupby()` to feed a function chunks like the above. The right side would be passed to the function, and I need the left side returned (or some index/order to get me to the left side).

---

Here's a reproducible example, using the same data as above, but adding a `group` column and another chunk so you can see my `groupby()` solution.

Setup and input jumbled data:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                   'date': [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
                   'old': [1, 8, 2, 2, 5, 5, 4, 10, 7],
                   'new': [2, 5, 5, 8, 2, 4, 7, 1, 10]})
print(df)

### jumbled: the `new` value of a row is not the same as the next row's `old` value
#   group  date  old  new
# 0     a     0    1    2
# 1     a     1    8    5
# 2     a     1    2    5
# 3     a     1    2    8
# 4     a     1    5    2
# 5     a     2    5    4
# 6     b     3    4    7
# 7     b     4   10    1
# 8     b     4    7   10
```

I wrote a kludgy solution that begs for a more elegant approach. See my gist [here](https://gist.github.com/jwhendy/2b83320eb33792adabb4c119ae09fced) for the code behind the `order_rows` function I call below. The output is correct:

```
df1 = df.copy()
df1 = df1.groupby(['group'], as_index=False, sort=False).apply(order_rows).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df1)

### correct: the `old` value in each row equals the `new` value of the previous row
#   group date old new
# 0     a    0   1   2
# 1     a    1   2   5
# 2     a    1   5   2
# 3     a    1   2   8
# 4     a    1   8   5
# 5     a    2   5   4
# 6     b    3   4   7
# 7     b    4   7  10
# 8     b    4  10   1
```

---

**Update based on `networkx` suggestion**

Note that bullet #2 above suggests that these ambiguous chunks can occur without a prior reference row. In that case, feeding the starting point as `df.iloc[0]` is not safe. In addition, I found that when seeding the graph with an incorrect starting point, it appears to only output the nodes it *could* successfully order. Note that 5 rows were passed, but only 4 values were returned.

Example:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
                   'date': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'old': [8, 1, 2, 2, 5],
                   'new': [5, 2, 5, 8, 2]})

g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df[['old', 'new']], 
                            source='old', 
                            target='new', 
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

ordered = np.asarray(list(nx.algorithms.traversal.edge_dfs(g, df.old[0])))
ordered

# array([[8, 5],
#        [5, 2],
#        [2, 5],
#        [2, 8]])
```

Comment: Could you explain more on how you got the desired output?

Comment: `Sometimes the entries occur within the granularity of the timestamps, so it's not possible to obtain the correct order by sorting alone` What do you mean? Do you have timestamps that are _exactly_ equal? That is very, very unlikely

Comment: @Vishnudev can you explain what you want? For example, do you mean how I came up with the code I proposed? Or how I know that the order is "correct."? If it's the latter, I've explained it: the order is correct when every `old` value equals the `new` value in the previous row.

Comment: @rafaelc So... I have to prove my conundrum to you? 1) when timestamps are `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M` (seconds are present, but always `00`), yes, at this granularity, the timestamps for some chunks of rows are *exactly* equal; the user entered multiple `old`/`new` value pairs within a minute. 2) This is irrelevant, however, as the problem is more general above. What is the most efficient way to get rows that have the same `i` value in the correct order?

Comment: @Hendy I'm just analyzing if you're not falling into a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you reading these timestamps from a file (e.g. a .csv file) ? If so, how are you reading them? In the raw file, are the granularities _also_ the same or are they different there?

Comment: @rafaelc Ah, fair enough. Then again, problems don't have to be *purely* real here, do they? Is this not an interesting problem/challenge for the SO community? :) I just referred to the raw excel dump I was given and arrowed through the first 1k rows of my ~300k; all end in `:00`.

Comment: @Hendy Relax, this is definitely a very decent problem :) . I'm just analyzing through different angles before tackling your attempted solution. I had a similar problem before - I was analyzing high freq trading data, and when I read from the `csv` file, they lost a great deal of precision on the way. Not sure if it was a pandas bug at that time. I had solved it by reading the datetime/timestamp column as strings (and thus not losing any precision) and _then_ converting to datetime using `pd.to_datetime`. That gave me the full precision of timestamps.

Comment: Now, to your problem - I can't understand the logic behind your new ordering. To me, it seems like you just reversed the order of rows with same `i`, without much logic to it. That sounds right?

Comment: @rafaelc I'll re-write the example. I think it speaks for itself, but I've also been looking at this problem for hours. While the reversal happens to be the case, please re-read my rule for when entries are in order: `old_i = new_(i-1)`. Yes, rows happened to be flipped in my example, but that doesn't mean "flip the rows" is always the answer. Stay tuned and thanks for looking.

Comment: `old_i = new_(i-1)` is not very helpful. From what I understand, it means that, for instance, `old_1 = new_0` , i.e. every `old` for `i=1` should have the value of `new_0` which is 2 in your first example. But that's not the case

Comment: @rafaelc Steps: put the rows in an order, then evaluate to see if `new_0=old_1`, `new_1=old_2`, ..., `new_(n-1)=old_n`. I've re-written the question with a graphical illustration. See if that clears things up. I'm not interpreting your question precisely, but you *might* be thinking of the values within columns as fluid. They are not, and are always treated as rows of pairs. You can re-arrange rows, but you cannot change the order of column values independently.

Comment: @rafaelc Also, once you understand fully, feel free to suggest a better explanation of the problem and I'm happy to update both the question/title for posterity. I find it hard to explain concisely and could not muster enough google-fu to find similar problems, but I'd bet this is a known "thing" in algorithms, I just don't know what it's called?

Answer (score 1):

This is a graph problem. You can use `networkx` to create your graph, and then use `numpy` for manipulation. A simple traversal algorithm, like [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), will visit all your edges starting from a source.

The source is simply your first node (i.e. `df.old[0]`)

To your example:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df[['old', 'new']], 
                            source='old', 
                            target='new', 
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

ordered = np.asarray(list(nx.algorithms.traversal.edge_dfs(g, df.old[0])))
```

---

```
>>>ordered
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 2,  5],
       [ 5,  2],
       [ 2,  8],
       [ 8,  5],
       [ 5,  4],
       [ 4,  7],
       [ 7, 10],
       [10,  1]])
```

You may just assign back to your data frame: `df[['old', 'new']] = ordered`. You might have to change some small details, e.g. if your groups are not inter-connected. But, if the starting point is a sorted df on `group` and `date` *and* the dependencies on `old_i = new_(i-1)` are respected inter-groups, then you should be fine to just assign back the `ordered` array.

I still believe, however, that you should investigate your timestamps. I believe this is a simpler problem that can be solved by just sorting the timestamps. Make sure you are not losing precision on your timestamps when reading/writing to files.

Comment: Will digest this shortly. I knew it must have a name! As mentioned, the xlsx dump I was given only has `00` for seconds. I can look up the chain and see. The data is from SalesForce.com entries...

Comment: Feedback after trying: 1) I didn't initially catch it, but this requires a seed. Note bullet 2 in the question that the ambiguous chunk sometimes exists alone. Namely, I don't have a ground truth for the first row in that case. 2) `df.old[0]` did not play well for me when using `groupby.apply()`. I used `df.iloc[0].old` successfully, though. I'd be interested in how you might workaround #1.

Comment: Added an example expanding on #1 and showing that it doesn't work with an incorrect first seed.